# Reduce or disable DNS cache in 10.13 and 10.14

Tags: terminal, network, dns, sudo

I'm trying to get a hold of the property list, I'm guessing, that specifies the TTL or the amount of records held of the DNS cache of the system, if is not user/root accessible, then command that edits it, hopefully.

I want to reduce the TTL or eliminate it, my local DNS servers are fast enough for continuous querying

-- **I do not want to flush it**,

I already know the commands for that, even made a script out of it. It takes like nothing but you still have to **sudo -i** to become root and go into root's home folder, where it made the most sense to store it if I'd have to superuser-myself anyway.

Reduce or kill, not flush.